# primary key column not visible by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am learning ASP.NET and trying to create two table using code first approach using MVC. Below is the model .cs file for Courses.

```
 public class Instructor
    {
        [Key]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string address_ { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
    public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Course")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CSExxx")]
        public string progId { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string semester { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("instructor")]
        public virtual string name { get; set; }
        public virtual Instructor instructor { get; set; }
    }
```

I added the corresponding controller and as expected views got generated automatically by visual studio. Once I ran the project and clicked on instructor menu below is the window which got opened.

[image]
Clearly I am not able to see the column **name** which I declared as PK. Now when I click on **Create New** then I am able to see four columns including the Primary key column which is **name**.
[image]

My Question why I am not able to see the primary key column in the main display.

Comment: The primary key should really be a **system-internal** identifier without any "real" meaning, and it's definitely not something the enduser should see or be able to input .

Comment: On a side note, it's customary to use Pascal-casing for properties, `ProgId` instead of `progId`.

Comment: @marc_s : I did not know that PK should be hidden. I just wanted to see via UI that PK is properly implemented or not. Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s : But when we create database we sometimes put the value of PK by ourselves. Suppose if PK is not the system generated "IDENTITY COLUMN" then we also insert the values sometimes. What if PK is SSN. Just wondering.

Comment: @Tanz: SSN is a **really bad** example - first of all, **it's** ***NOT*** unique! And second of all - it's use as a "identifying element" in IT systems is explicitly discouraged (if not even forbidden - not sure about the details). But if you have a "natural" PK - something in your "actual" data that can act as the PK - then yes, you have to offer input to the user, obviously. **HOWEVER:** in my 25+ years of DB experience, this has happened ....... *very close* to **never!**

Comment: A **good** primary key must be **(1)** unique and **(2)** non-nullable, and it should be **(3)** stable (never change, if possible) and if ever possible **(4)** made up from a single, narrow column. This *hardly ever* applies to anything in your actual data being stored.

Comment: @marc_s: Why we should never show the PK to the user?

Comment: The user doesn't need to know what the PK value is - it's an **internal** system value - no point in "bothering" the user with that info....

Comment: @Tanz, To use a database accurately and effectively the users do of course need to see and use keys. The issue you are coming up against here is the assumption that your database tables will also have purely technical keys which are internal to the database. Such keys don't need to be visible to users because they will use alternative identifiers instead. "Hidden" technical keys are not intended to be a replacement for the "real" keys that users are familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The templates and code generators at work here assume a technical key, ie one that is not visible or meaningful to the user.

Your choice of `name` is debatable, the simple solution here is to introduce

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

in all your classes. If you do want to stick to the name, then simply edit the generated cshtml.

Comment: Ohkey. I kind of got your point. Actually I am learning these things so I wanted to create a primary key which I can really see. Supposing I have to show to my professor via UI  that I have really implemented a primary key concept and I want to show him that since I have primary key declared I cannot enter duplicate values. I cannot do that with my piece of code. Or the approach you are suggesting. Because I am guessing even if I keep the ID column as PK; it will not be visible.

Comment: You mean to say I have to manually edit the "indexcs.html"  that got generated?!

Comment: Yes. It's just a simple starter template anyway.